# How to find a variance of sample sequence

Tags: signal-analysis, autocorrelation, random-process, stationary

I have a sequence such as

$$r[n] = y[n]v[n]$$

$y[n]$ and $v[n]$ are zero-mean and statistically independent.

I need to find a variance of $r[n]$ and show that it is white and equal to $\sigma ^2_y\sigma^2_v$.

I know that $y[n]$ has variance of $\sigma ^2_y$ and I also know that
$$Cor(v_n, v_{n+m}) = \sigma ^2_v\delta[m]$$

This is what I have so far :

Finding the variance of $r[n]$:
$$\sigma_r^2 = \mathbb{E}([r[n]-m_r)^2]=\mathbb{E}[r^2[n]] - 2\mathbb{E}[r[n]]m_r+m_r^2$$

Then

$$\sigma_r^2 = \mathbb{E}[r^2[n]] - 2m_r m_r+m_r^2 = \mathbb{E}[r^2[n]]-m_r^2 $$

I am stuck at this point. Could you suggest how do I proceed from here?

The process is WSS random process.

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE! Are $y[n]$ and $v[n]$ uncorrelated? Do you know the means of these processes?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's only very peripherally a signal processing question – especially, there's a post on cross-validated, the stat/stoch sister SE site, that answers this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52646/variance-of-product-of-multiple-random-variables

Comment: Hi @Tendero , yes y[n]  and v[n] are zero-mean and statistically independent

Comment: @ViniLL. How about taking the time to **edit** your question so as to put the **important information** that $y[n]$ and $v[n]$  are zero-mean and independent right up there as part of the question instead of just being tucked away in a comment that a reader might well miss? -1 pending the edit requested.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Question is edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\sigma_r^2=\sigma_y^2\sigma_v^2$ iff

1) $\mathbb{E}\{y\} = \mathbb{E}\{v\}=0$.

AND

2) $y$ and $v$ are independent, OR uncorrelated and their squares ($y^2$ and $v^2$) are also uncorrelated.

---

Proof: assuming independence,

$\sigma_r^2=\mathbb{E}\{(yv-\mathbb{E}\{yv\})^2\}$ (by definition)

$~~~~=\mathbb{E}\{(yv-\mathbb{E}\{y\}\mathbb{E}\{v\})^2\}$ (by independence)

$~~~~=\mathbb{E}\{y^2v^2+\mathbb{E}^2\{y\}\mathbb{E}^2\{v\}-2yv\mathbb{E}\{y\}\mathbb{E}\{v\}\}$

$~~~~=\mathbb{E}\{y^2v^2\}-\mathbb{E}^2\{y\}\mathbb{E}^2\{v\}$

$~~~~=\mathbb{E}\{y^2\}\mathbb{E}\{v^2\}-\mathbb{E}^2\{y\}\mathbb{E}^2\{v\}$ (by independence, since the square function is a measurable function).\

But, $\mathbb E\{y^2\} = \sigma_y^2 + \mathbb E^2\{y\}$
and $\mathbb E\{v^2\} = \sigma_v^2 + \mathbb E^2\{v\}$ and so,
\begin{align}\sigma_r^2&=(\sigma_y^2 + \mathbb E^2\{y\})(\sigma_v^2 + \mathbb E^2\{v\}) - \mathbb E^2\{y\}\mathbb E^2\{v\}\\
&= \sigma_y^2\sigma_v^2 + \sigma_y^2\mathbb E^2\{v\} +
\sigma_v^2\mathbb E^2\{y\}
\end{align}

which *does not* equal $\sigma_y^2\sigma_v^2$ unless *both* $y$ and $v$ have zero mean as the OP has stated: having *at least* one mean be zero (which does not preclude the other mean from being *nonzero*) is not enough (as was claimed in an earlier version of this answer).

---

Proof: assuming $y,v$ uncorrelated and $y^2,v^2$ *also* uncorrelated,

\begin{align}\sigma_r^2 &=\mathbb{E}\left[(yv-\mathbb{E}[yv])^2\right] &{\scriptstyle{\text{(by definition)}}}\\
&=\mathbb{E}\left[(yv-\mathbb{E}[y]\mathbb{E}[v])^2\right]  & {\scriptstyle{E[yv]=E[y]E[v] ~\text{since}~ y ~\text{and}~v~\text{are uncorrelated}}}\\
&=\mathbb{E}\left[y^2v^2\right] &{\scriptstyle{\mathbb E[y] = \mathbb E[v]  = 0~\text{by assumption}}}\\
&=\mathbb{E}[y^2]\mathbb{E}[v^2] &{\scriptstyle{E[y^2v^2]=E[y^2]E[v^2] ~\text{since}~ y^2 ~\text{and}~v^2~\text{are uncorrelated}}}\\
&= \sigma_y^2\sigma_v^2 &{\scriptstyle{\text{since}~\mathbb E[y]= \mathbb E[v] = 0~\text{by assumption}}}
\end{align}

Note that $y$ and $v$ being independent is a *subcase* of the above assumptions about $y$ and $v$ being uncorrelated and $y^2$ and $v^2$ *also* being uncorrelated.  When $y$ and $v$ are independent (and hence uncorrelated), so are $y^2$ and $v^2$ independent (which implies that $y^2$ and $v^2$ are uncorrelated).

Comment: Hi @Sofiane, thanks for answer, sorry for forgetting to mention that y[n]  and v[n] are zero mean and statistically independent

Comment: Actually, you also need to state that the independence of $y$ and $v$ also guarantees that $y^2$ and $v^2$ are independent and thus we can factor $E\big[r^2[n]\big]$ as $$E\big[r^2[n]\big] = E\big[y^2[n]v^2[n]\big] = E\big[y^2[n]\big]E\big[v^2[n]\big].$$ With regard to the "if and only if", note that it suffices if $y$ and $v$ are _uncorrelated_ and so are $y^2$ and $v^2$; independence is _not_ necessary.

Comment: @DilipSarwate thanks , I see, but considering what you said where does $$m_r^2 $$ term in my last equation dissapears?

Comment: @DilipSarwate $x^2$ is measurable, so if $y$ and $v$ are independent, the squared processes are also independent.

Comment: @ViniLL does it solve, or I have to show the detailed calculus?

Comment: @Sofiane Yes, independence and measurability of the squaring operation do imply that $y^2$ and $v^2$ are independent but you need to _say_ so in view of the level at which the question is asked. And the “ only if” part is still wrong: $y$ and $v$ being uncorrelated and $y^2$ and $v^2$ also being uncorrelated suffices, independence is not necessary.

Comment: @Sofiane yes please, because I can't really see how to put it all together.. First of all , are my equation till the last point correct? If yes, how do I apply what you and Dilip said in order to get the final answer   $$r[n] =  σ_y^2σ_v^2 $$

Comment: @ViniLL  Read the answer (by me!) to the question on stats.SE that Marcus Muller found. It's all there in detail without the brevity that Sofiane seems to feel is necessary.

Comment: @ViniLL The detailed calculus is added.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Sorry, but I can't find anything like the propriety of measurable function in r.v.'s dependence that can be applied in covariance. I.e., measurable functions preserve independence but I can't find anything for the covariance. So I'm not sure if they also preserve uncorrelation.

Comment: @Sofiane I didn't claim that squaring preserved uncorrelation: I said "$y$ and $v$ being uncorrelated and $y^2$ and $v^2$ _also_ being uncorrelated suffices," (I emphasized _also_ in the quote above: I should have emphasized it in the original comment).  I have added the proof for the other case to your answer.

Comment: @Sofiane thanks so much, I see how it works now.

Answer (score 2):

from

> Goodman, Leo A. "On the exact variance of products." Journal of the
>   American statistical association 55.292 (1960): 708-713.

or

> Bohrnstedt, George W., and Arthur S. Goldberger. "On the exact
>   covariance of products of random variables." Journal of the American
>   Statistical Association 64.328 (1969): 1439-1442.

the variance of the product of $z=xy$ , $x$ and $y$ independent.

$$
\sigma_z^2=m_x^2 \sigma_y^2 +  m_y^2 \sigma_x^2 + \sigma_x^2 \sigma_y^2
$$
where $E\{x\}=m_x$ and the same for $y$

Bohrstein and Goldberger's  derivation is easier to follow but Goodman isn't behind a paywall.

The papers also cover the dependent case which is a bit more complicated.